# Show error message if file_get_contents return null

Tags: php

> I want to show an error message in error.php page if file_get_contents return null.
>   This is my code where i get value from url.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $msg = "";
    $data = file_get_contents('http://apis.sdf.sdf/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/' . $number);

    $datas = json_decode($data);

    $originalDate = strtotime($datas[0]->DATE);
    $newDate = date('F jS Y', $originalDate);
    if ($datas[0] == "") {//echo 'hello';exit;
        $msg = "No data avialable.";
        header('location:error.php');
    }
    ?
```

> this is the out put of file_get_contents

[{"ID":103,"LRGODAWN":"BAJARKABATI ROAD","LRSUFIX":"BK","LRGODAWNID":1,"VEHICLE_NO":"OD-05-N-3856","VEHICLEID":799,"basic_freight":320.00,}]

> this is error.php page where i want to show error message if file_get_contents return null.

```
       <section>
        <div class="container" id="load" >             
            <div class="body_left" id="container">             
                <span>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($msg))
                        echo $msg;
                    ?>
                </span> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: so what is that you are facing? cant see the error message?

Comment: header('location:error.php?msg='.$msg);   on error.php echo $_GET['msg'];

Comment: page not redirect to error .php page it still on tracking .php(where i get file_get_contents value)

Comment: ini_set('display_errors','On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); on the debug mode

Answer (score 1):

You need make some session to show message on another PHP page,
on current page when you have $msg argument you need change to

```
$_SESSION["message"] = 'No data avialable.';
```

And in your error.php on top of PHP file you need put (this code allow you to get current message from session and put in variable msg and unset your session if you dont unset your message will show you all time):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    $msg = $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```